# How to invoke two visual studio projects repeatedly in a loop

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have two visual studio projects. I want to do something like

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{  
    Run_Project1(i)          // Pass i as argument to project 1.
    Run_Project2(i)
    // do something with results
}
```

How can I possibly do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all you need to compile the projects and get the resulting executable files, you can't simply "run" source code.

The next thing to do is to call the exe files, the easy way to do that in win32 is with system. So you would run something like

```
while( itPleasesYou ){
    system("Path/proj1.exe args");
    system("Path/proj2.exe args");
}
```

As for how you get the results, well you'd need to specify what those would be.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what you want to achieve. Maybe you want to compile and run multiple projects in batch. In that case,

Create a batch file with the following code and run it

```
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,10) DO (
devenv "project%%i.vcxproj" /RunExit
)
```